# dnf won't let me overwrite or change packages

Tags: software-installation, dnf, compatibility, llvm

I want to do something that is supposed to be simple in any package manager, install a package, in my case it is this specifically `lib64MLIRVectorToSPIRV13`.

```js
LC_ALL=C dnf install lib64MLIRVectorToSPIRV13
```

The problem is that a `yum` dependency was installed, and it is not possible to uninstall it, because it is supposedly from the system, while I am using dnf.

I couldn't run yum, because it was missing crypto symbols (and I couldn't migrate it to Python 3), so what I did was simply make a symbolic link from `dnf` to `yum`.

Leaving that topic aside, what I want is to be able to overwrite, change, remove or reinstall the packages that are interfering in order to install `lib64MLIRVectorToSPIRV13`

Yes, I can install all the packages one by one, although it would be better with the package manager, unless there is a package on the Internet that contains all of the ***LLVM 13***.

But I get this error...

```js
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 from install of lib64stdc++6-11.2.0-2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so.6 conflicts between attempted installs of lib64ncursesw6-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and lib64ncursesw6-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64
```

## History of my operating system

I'm using a 2006 Commodore purchased at *Garbarino* shopping.

```js
CPU~Dual core Pentium E5700 (-MCP-) speed/max~2611/2965 MHz Kernel~5.7.2-lxpup64 x86_64 Up~7:52 Mem~1167.9/1990.8MB HDD~95.6GB(73.6% used) Procs~155 Client~Shell inxi~2.3.8
```

The system I use is *LxPupSc64 20.06*, which is *PuppyLinux*, in turn based on *WOFF* and Slackware, with a modification so that it can support various package managers.

How could I install another package manager? The way I managed to install the package manager was by downloading each missing package from the ***pkgs.org*** page.

The package manager that I was able to install was pacman from *ArchLinux*, then since the *Nouveau* driver no longer starts because the system was updated, I installed another package manager, which is dnf.

I couldn't install *apt-get* or *snapd*, or any package that uses *systemd*, since *PuppyLinux* also works without `sudo`.

Log:

```js
Last metadata expiration check: 0:05:38 ago on Mon Mar 25 06:52:00 2024.
Dependencies resolved.
=========================================================================================================
 Package                                            Arch        Version               Repository    Size
=========================================================================================================
Installing:
 lib64MLIRVectorToSPIRV13                           x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       33 k
Installing dependencies:
 cross-aarch64-openmandriva-linux-gnu-libc          x86_64      6:2.34-6              release       62 M
 lib64LLVMDemangle13                                x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      110 k
 lib64LLVMSupport13                                 x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      806 k
 lib64MLIRAffine13                                  x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      162 k
 lib64MLIRAnalysis13                                x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       84 k
 lib64MLIRCallInterfaces13                          x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       10 k
 lib64MLIRControlFlowInterfaces13                   x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       18 k
 lib64MLIRDataLayoutInterfaces13                    x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       28 k
 lib64MLIRDialectUtils13                            x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       26 k
 lib64MLIRIR13                                      x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      483 k
 lib64MLIRInferTypeOpInterface13                    x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       15 k
 lib64MLIRLinalg13                                  x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      701 k
 lib64MLIRLoopAnalysis13                            x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      139 k
 lib64MLIRMath13                                    x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       47 k
 lib64MLIRMemRef13                                  x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      192 k
 lib64MLIRMemRefUtils13                             x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       12 k
 lib64MLIRPDL13                                     x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       90 k
 lib64MLIRPDLInterp13                               x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      118 k
 lib64MLIRPDLToPDLInterp13                          x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       90 k
 lib64MLIRParser13                                  x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      115 k
 lib64MLIRPass13                                    x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      102 k
 lib64MLIRPresburger13                              x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       34 k
 lib64MLIRRewrite13                                 x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      122 k
 lib64MLIRSCF13                                     x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      113 k
 lib64MLIRSPIRV13                                   x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      698 k
 lib64MLIRSPIRVConversion13                         x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       43 k
 lib64MLIRSideEffectInterfaces13                    x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       13 k
 lib64MLIRStandard13                                x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      237 k
 lib64MLIRSupport13                                 x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       56 k
 lib64MLIRTensor13                                  x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      109 k
 lib64MLIRTransformUtils13                          x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      231 k
 lib64MLIRVector13                                  x86_64      13.0.0-1              release      353 k
 lib64MLIRVectorInterfaces13                        x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       11 k
 lib64MLIRViewLikeInterface13                       x86_64      13.0.0-1              release       18 k
 lib64ncursesw6                                     x86_64      6.3-1.20211219.2      release      173 k
 lib64stdc++6                                       x86_64      11.2.0-2              release      647 k
Installing weak dependencies:
 cross-aarch64-openmandriva-linux-gnu-binutils      x86_64      2.37-1                release      2.7 M
 cross-aarch64-openmandriva-linux-gnu-gcc           x86_64      11.2.0-2              release       86 M

Transaction Summary
=========================================================================================================
Install  39 Packages

Total size: 157 M
Installed size: 1.5 G
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
[SKIPPED] cross-aarch64-openmandriva-linux-gnu-binutils-2.37-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded   
[SKIPPED] cross-aarch64-openmandriva-linux-gnu-gcc-11.2.0-2-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded      
[SKIPPED] cross-aarch64-openmandriva-linux-gnu-libc-2.34-6-omv4003.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded       
[SKIPPED] lib64LLVMDemangle13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                           
[SKIPPED] lib64LLVMSupport13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                            
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRAffine13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                             
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRAnalysis13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                           
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRCallInterfaces13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                     
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRControlFlowInterfaces13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded              
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRDataLayoutInterfaces13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRDialectUtils13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                       
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRIR13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                 
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRInferTypeOpInterface13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRLinalg13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                             
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRLoopAnalysis13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                       
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRMath13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                               
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRMemRef13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                             
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRMemRefUtils13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                        
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRPDL13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRPDLInterp13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                          
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRPDLToPDLInterp13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                     
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRParser13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                             
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRPass13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                               
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRPresburger13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                         
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRRewrite13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                            
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRSCF13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRSPIRV13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                              
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRSPIRVConversion13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                    
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRSideEffectInterfaces13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded               
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRStandard13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                           
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRSupport13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                            
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRTensor13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                             
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRTransformUtils13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                     
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRVector13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                             
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRVectorInterfaces13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                   
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRVectorToSPIRV13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                      
[SKIPPED] lib64MLIRViewLikeInterface13-13.0.0-1-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                  
[SKIPPED] lib64ncursesw6-6.3-1.20211219.2-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                        
[SKIPPED] lib64stdc++6-11.2.0-2-omv4050.x86_64.rpm: Already downloaded                                  
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 from install of lib64stdc++6-11.2.0-2.x86_64 conflicts with file from package libstdc++-4.8.5-44.el7.x86_64
  file /usr/lib64/libncursesw.so.6 conflicts between attempted installs of lib64ncursesw6-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64 and lib64ncursesw6-6.3-1.20211219.2.x86_64
```

Comment: @ArtEze please provide a way for us to understand how you ended up with a mixture of three distros? That *must* break! So, you must have taken special precautions to make it safe to install software. We can't guess these; you'll really have to tell us. Frankly, at this point, a reasonable admin would flatten the system and set it up from scratch, using *one* distro, but I guess you're not doing that because of specific reasons, which we also don't know.

Comment: @MarcusMüller As I already explained, I use packages from pkgs.org, downloading and extracting the pacman packages one by one, then with pacman install dnf, this is because the package manager that PuppyLinux comes with is very bad and very slow. I am using a very old PC with very low resources, buying a new one would cost me a fortune and I don't have enough money at the moment.

Comment: This has nothing to do with having a slow PC. What you're doing is just insane; a consistent distro works just as well on older hardware. Installing dnf with pacman doesn't mean you can suddenly use RPM packaged software. That's not at all how software packaging works; I'm sorry. The easiest way out here is to take your PC, and install a clean operating system; none of what you're doing here is close to making sense :(

Comment: @MarcusMüller I only have 2 GB of RAM and 75 GB of hard drive, external video card and I cannot install another system, the others use systemd, which makes it even slower and requires more disk reading and writing. It is the only system I could install that works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152227/discussion-between-arteze-and-marcus-muller).

Comment: that is a myth. Systemd makes your system not any slower, nor does it add read or write overhead. You really really just broke your system in multiple ways. I'm sorry, but I don't think investing time in "salvaging" it is well-invested time :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to remove the protection from `yum`.

I don't remember now exactly which file I deleted, but it said something about **protected**. The file was in a subfolder of the following folder.

```
/etc/dnf
```

When I was able to remove the protection, I removed the package that was interfering, and after that the entire system was ruined, and it became unusable.

Fortunately, I already had a fairly updated session of the system in Puppy Linux...

And now I am only using pacman instead of dnf, but if LLVM fails again when updating the system, I will have to install dnf again, or perhaps report the error in the LLVM repositories.

Answer (score 2):

I get the impression there are a number of misconceptions or misinterpretations involved here. I don’t think it’s useful to try to fix your package installation problem, but I’ll try to address the misconceptions.

The first is that, while Puppy Linux does appear to be designed to support installation of packages from a variety of systems, it does so using its own package manager. As a general rule, each distribution’s package manager is a core piece of that distribution, and you can’t install multiple package managers to manage the same system.

Even when distributions use the same package format and package management tools, you can’t mix packages from them; for example Ubuntu packages work on Ubuntu, and while some work on Debian too, adding Ubuntu packages to a Debian system is a recipe for failure at some point down the line.

The second is that `apt-get` and co rely on `sudo` or systemd. `apt-get` is a tool; what distributions using it end up doing is a choice of the distribution, not `apt-get`. `apt-get` works fine when run as root whether through `sudo` or not; since you seem to have packages managing files in `/lib64` and `/usr/lib64`, I imagine you’re running your package manager(s) as root. `apt-get` also doesn’t depend on systemd; Devuan uses `apt-get` and doesn’t use systemd.

I understand you want to avoid systemd because you’ve associated it with hard-drive errors you encountered in the past. It is *extremely* unlikely that the two are related.

Since your ultimate goal seems to be to run warzone2100 on your system, I would recommend starting over with a distribution that has warzone2100 available as a package. You can look [at the relevant page on Repology](https://repology.org/project/warzone2100/versions) to find those distributions; note that some are whole families of distributions. Debian should work fine on your system, perhaps with a lighter-weight desktop environment than the default GNOME; you can choose desktop environments during installation. If you really want to avoid systemd, try Devuan, it has warzone2100 too.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I just made a response explaining how after unprotecting yum the system became unusable. The problem I have is that Puppy's package manager is very bad, in general the whole system was too bad, but by using Pacman I was able to solve most of the problems. Warzone 2100 now works, so I can't reproduce the error I reported in Mesa again.

Comment: Perhaps I wasn’t clear enough: it really is a bad idea to switch package managers. If you don’t like Puppy’s package manager, you should switch distributions, not just the package manager.

Comment: It's quite a topic, because first I would need to install grub2 (now using pacman), I don't know how to do it, I'm currently using grub4dos, which is very limited to be able to load new systems. I would like to be able to install 4MLinux, I never tried it, but it looks good in the internet videos.

Comment: Usually the distribution’s installer takes care of that for you.

Comment: But if I install another system I will lose all the files, that's why I wanted to install grub2.

Comment: I don’t understand the connection between the two. Ideally the data you care about is backed up (and that doesn’t have to incur additional cost, you can store encrypted backups in the free tiers of various cloud providers). In any case, if you shrink your existing partition(s), you can install a new distribution in the free space on your system. That will take care of the bootloader.

Comment: I would need to install grub2 on the USB if I want to make a backup, because if I delete the current system I will be left without systems, and if the system is deleted I would not be able to access the cloud either.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152249/discussion-between-arteze-and-stephen-kitt).